# Where to see the logging.error() message i put in code when visit a page using azure web portal

Tags: django, azure, azure-web-app-service

I create a web app on Azure using Django framework. I import the logging lib and trying to display a error message (logging.error('msg')). However, i couldn't find where exactly can i see the error message log in azure portal. Thanks for the advice if any. Thank you

Comment: Where does your logging library normally log when the web app is hosted on premise? Please provide more details.

Comment: Hi, it was previously deployed on google cloud platform. i am trying out azure. previously on google cloud, the logging is captured automatically without configuration and i can view the log on web panel of google cloud. I am wondering does azure support the same. So far, I can see as suggested below, it seems like necessary setting is required.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify where you want to capture your log data in your settings.py file, you can also configure it to be mailed if you want.

Here is sample setting below to capture you log data into a file.

added these code `settings.py` file

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'formatters': {
        'basic': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s %(name)-20s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        },
        'default': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'formatter': 'basic',
            'filename': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'log.txt'),
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'app1': {
            'handlers': ['default'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,

        },
        'app2': {
            'handlers': ['default'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,

        },
    }
}
```

Added your app name instead of app1 or app2 above. This settings will create a log file with respect to your BASE_DIR

For more detail https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/logging/

Comment: hi, I tried this, but where can i view the log file on Azure?

Comment: I just want to display simple text on console maybe. is there any simple method i can do with Azure instead write the log in file?